# How to check if help for form element exists?

Tags: twig

Is there any way to check if form help exists directly in Twig template?

Pseudocode:

```
{% if formName.formField.help %}
    {# ... #}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
{% if formName.formField.vars.help is not null %}
    {# ... #}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is just to use the filter [`default`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.html) (*if the value is not boolean though*)

```
{% if formName.formField.vars.help|default %}
    true
{% else %}
    false
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/ol0fms)